# How to get the API structured data against the unique id in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6

I have a data structure like this

```
 data ={
       id1 : {name:'',email:''},
       id2 : {name:'',email:''},
       id3 : {name:'',email:''}
}
```

and the id is 20 digit unique key
How can i get this type of data i have tried using this code but not working

```
 Object.keys(seller_data).map((data,index) => {
              return <div key={index}>
                 <div>Firebase Data</div>
                 {Object.keys(seller_data[data]).map(
                val => <div>{seller_data[data][val]}</div> )
                 }
               </div>
```

Comment: can you share result or error if you have?

Comment: btw you forgot closing bracket for first map

Comment: Undefined its showing

Comment: https://codesandbox.io/s/musing-gareth-lsuib?file=/src/App.js check this pls

Comment: TypeError: Cannot convert undefined or null to object

Comment: I updated code check pls. is it helpfull or not

Comment: state==> {
-MMLDd_d0d38VEs4f9TP: {…},
 -MMLDhYFgB0-iyR8ZmYv: {…},
 -MMLDog98cQ2XlqTNQGb: {…}
-MMLDd_d0d38VEs4f9TP: {add_description: "", add_photo: "blob:https://localhost:3000/9063ef55-aac6-484a-949d-56eab1c0940d",
}

Comment: I am getting this data on console and                                                                                
 let seller_data = this.state.firebaseData[0]; //this where i store the data from firebase

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/224691/discussion-between-aliaga-aliyev-and-yaxir-bajwa).